# Differential equations and Kalman filters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, signal-processing, kalman-filter

I have been told that every differential equation has an associated Kalman filter. How do we get the Kalman filter of a given differential equation. For example let's say we have $$my''+cy'+ky=f(x)$$ What is the associated Kalman filter?

Comment: Where is the 'noise' in your equation?

Comment: I'm not sure. Do I need noise?

Comment: The Kalman filter is an optimal filter for the estimation of a signal in the noise. Your equation is detrministic